# How to set foreign key in android sqlite

Tags: android

How to set the primary key of CREATE_PARENT_M_LIST table as foreign key to CREATE_CHILD_M_LIST

Here are my queries.

```
// My parent table.
public static String CREATE_PARENT_M_LIST = "create table if not exists "+
DATABASE_TABLE1 + " ( p_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "table_name text);"; 

// my child table.
public static String CREATE_CHILD_M_LIST = "create table if not exists "
        + DATABASE_TABLE2 + " ( id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + " symbol text," + " f_id integer," 
        + " foregin key(f_id) references " + DATABASE_TABLE1 + "(p_id));";
```

I am getting syntax error near f_id column

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

becouse you got a spelling error:

```
foregin key(f_id) references
```

change it to

```
foreign key(f_id) references
```